Flutter cameraController is taking above 5 seconds to capture image
onPressed i'm taking the image but it is taking more than 5 seconds to capture the image
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TakePictureScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.camera,
  });

  final CameraDescription camera;

  @override
  TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

This above is the main class
  late CameraController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = CameraController(widget.camera, ResolutionPreset.low,
        enableAudio: false);
    // _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (mounted) {
        _controller.setFocusMode(FocusMode.auto);
      }
    });
  }

and in the onPressed i'm taking the picture
  onPressed: () async {
                        
                        final image = await _controller.takePicture();
}

But this image capturing is taking above 5 seconds to capture the image.
I have tried another camera package and image_picker package it is redirecting to the phones camera  , and it is working properly. But i want to capture the image within the application without any lag .

dependencies:
  camera: ^0.10.0+1  # Example version, check for the latest

await cameraController.setFlashMode(FlashMode.off);
cameraController = CameraController(
  cameras[0], // Choose the camera
  ResolutionPreset.high,
  enableAudio: false,
);
await cameraController.initialize();
cameraController = CameraController(
  cameras[0],
  ResolutionPreset.medium,
);
try {
  final XFile image = await cameraController.takePicture();
  // Handle the captured image
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}

